# Pass data between components in Angular 4

Tags: angular

I have list component which list Group item as table. One of the link is allow user to edit item. Edit item is separate component. When user click on edit, i need to pass existing data to edit component. How can i do that?

Here is my list component

```
    <div class='table-responsive'>
    <table class='table' *ngIf='groups && groups.length'>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Avatar Image</th>
                <th>Display Name</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Member Count</th>
                <th>Total Post</th>
                <th>Last Modify Date</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr *ngFor='let group of groups | groupFilter:listFilter'>
            <td><img [src]='group.group_avatar_image' class="img-responsive" style="max-height: 50px;"></td>
            <td><a [href]='group.url'>{{group.display_name}}</a></td>
            <td>{{group.description}}</td>
            <td>{{group.total_members_count}}</td>
            <td>{{group.total_posts}}</td>
            <td>{{group.updated_at | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
            <td><a href="#"  [routerLink]="['/Edit Group']">Edit</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Here is my list component

```js
import { Component, OnInit,Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Group } from '../groupModel';
import { GroupsService } from '../groups.service';

@Component ({
    selector: 'groups-lst',
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: 'groups-list.component.html'
    //styleUrls: ['groups.component.css']
})

export class GroupsList implements OnInit{

    constructor(private _groupsService: GroupsService) {}

    title: string = 'Groups List';
    listFilter: string = '';
    errorMessage: string;
    
    groups: Group[];

        ngOnInit():void{
            this._groupsService.getGroups()
            .subscribe (group => this.groups = group,
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
        }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is one important thing about your approach to mention. It seems like you are thinking about a way to pass an instance of your model to the router. This is not possible **by design** (for sure, there are ways around like using a service as intermediary, but don't recommend that).

You should think about, that your records displayed within the grid might (and should) have identifiers, like an ordinary `id` property. The most common practice is to pass that identifier as parameter to the route and fetch the entity from source again.

**Grid component:**

```
<tr *ngFor='let group of groups | groupFilter:listFilter'>
   <td><img [src]='group.group_avatar_image' class="img-responsive" style="max-height: 50px;"></td>
   <td><a [href]='group.url'>{{group.display_name}}</a></td>
   <td>{{group.description}}</td>
   <td>{{group.total_members_count}}</td>
   <td>{{group.total_posts}}</td>
   <td>{{group.updated_at | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
   <td><a href="#"  [routerLink]="['/Edit', group.id]">Edit</a></td>
</tr>
```

In your "edit component" you can use the passed parameter to fetch your group entity:

```
private route$ : Subscription;
constructor(private route : ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit() {
   this.route$ = this.route.params.subscribe(
   (params : Params) => {
      let id = params["id"];
      // fetch the group entity from service / store
   });
}
```

And for sure you need to configure your route to recognize the `id` parameter:

```
export const routes = [
    ...
    { path : 'Edit/:id', component : ...},
    ...
];
```

Answer (score 0):

If components are not related by hierarchy (other than being in the same app) a service allowing subscription to a Subject is the way I usually go.

If components are easily related by hierarchy (parent/child), you can use Outputs.

Note that the service can be used for everything. However, I typically find myself using both.

There is a TON of documentation, and piles of samples, on both (some of which I've written right here on SO). The info you need is definitely available in a variety of questions. I'd be surprised if this question didn't get a dupe flag.

Here is a very bare-bones example of a Subject service, which you inject into any component that needs to "hear" a notification:

```
const Notes = {
    SOME_NAMED_EVENT : 'some_named_event',
    ... (more named events)
};

class Note {
    constructor ( name = '', data = {} ) {
        this.name = name;
        this.data = data;
    }
}

// Example of a subscription/notification style service,
// as opposed to a service that just calls a callback
class NotifierService {

    constructor() {
        let Rx = require ( 'rxjs' );
        this.subject = new Rx.Subject ( );
    }

    subscribe ( callback ) {
        return this.subject.subscribe ( b => callback ( b ) );
    }

    sendNote ( note ) {
        this.subject.next ( note );
    }
}
export { NotifierService, Notes, Note }
```